# Написание макросов в Word 2003 с помошью редактора Visual Basic

Tags: visual-basic, макросы

Имеееться текст New Roman Cyr,14pt. Нужно сотворить макрос, который будет делать следуйщее: Слова, написаные полужирным шрифтом, дополняет крассным цветом делает двойное подчёркивание. Никогда не стыкалась с Visual Basic, потому для меня это не понятно. О, великие мудрецы программирования, склоняюсь перед вашей величественостью;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да пожалуйста:)

```
Sub macros()
'Берем текст нашего документа текущего
Set Content = ActiveDocument.Content
'Слова в нем
Set Words = Content.Words
'Теперь бегаем по всем словам
For i = 1 To Words.Count
    Set currentWord = Words.Item(i)
    'Проверяем не жирный ли шрифт, тут можно проверять чего угодно, там вариантов масса
    If currentWord.Font.Bold = True Then
        'устанавливаем цвет для данного слова
        currentWord.Font.Color = wdColorRed
        'и подчеркиваем дважды
        currentWord.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineDouble
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Вот как-то так. У меня сработало, будут ошибки, обращайтесь.
Возможно есть даже функции, которые выдают массив слов в тексте по определенному критерию и работают естественно быстрее, поэтому, могу сказать, что код не оптимальный.

Comment: как круто...спасибо огромное))
а какая литературка может  хоть немного но пополнить мои знания, которых на данный момент нету, в синтаксисе этого языка?)

Comment: А даже не знаю, этот язык я учил по примерам и методом проб и ошибок.
Для VBS у меня только одна очень удобный HTMLHelp (*.chm), который описывает базовые функции и структуры языка. Только где-то я этот файл посеял.